# Не могу создать цикл для операции xor

Tags: c++

Наткнулся на задание с шифрованием через XOR. В нем было сказано, что нужно вводить ключ в программу 3-мя способами. Последний из них: ключ вводится в прямой последовательности, а потом в обратной. То есть "ШифррфиШ", а символы текста, который шифруется, просто идут прямо себе. Никак не могу понять, какой создать для этого цикл. Спасайте, я тупенький. Только не предлагайте создать сам ключ, который повторяет себя наоборот, мне именно циклом надо)

Answer (score 1):

Извращение делать это одним циклом вместо двух последовательных, но вот: https://ideone.com/Q34qbh

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  cin >> s;

  for (size_t q=1, n=0, w=~0U; q<s.length(); ++q)
    if (n)
      cout << s[q] << ' ' << s[++w %= n] << endl;
    else if (equal(s.begin(), s.begin()+q, s.rend()-1-q))
      n = q+1 >> 1;

  return 0;
}
```

Вариант с двумя циклами: https://ideone.com/jt6ImD

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  size_t n;

  cin >> s;

  for (n=2; n<s.length() && !equal(s.begin(), s.begin()+n-1, s.rend()-n); ++n);
  n >>= 1;

  for (size_t q=n+1, w=0; q<s.length(); ++q, ++w%=n)
    cout << s[q] << ' ' << s[w] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще я не имел в виду, что только одним. А двумя я пытался и у меня чет не вышло. Можете, пожалуйста, показать, как это сделать двумя?

Comment: я не понел: для чего  size_t  w=~0U?

Comment: @Артем, дополнил. По сути то же самое, просто вместо if внутри for два for'а.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, это `-1`. Пожалуй, правильнее было написать `~size_t()`.